# Custom async / await

Tags: c#

I am trying to re-write an asynchronous TCP class I once wrote implementing the new await/async construct.

So far I have

```
    public async void Send(byte[] data)
    {
        await SendAsync(data);
    }

    private Task SendAsync(byte[] data)
    {
        var stream = _tcpClient.GetStream();
        return new Task(()=>stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length));
    }
```

but something smells odd. Is this the correct way of doing it?

**Edit:**
For instance, I could achieve the same with

```
    public async void Send(byte[] data)
    {
        await SendAsync(data);
        var stream = _tcpClient.GetStream();
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length));
    }
```

or using Task.Run(..)

which is preferred?

Comment: You are not starting the task, is that on purpose?

Comment: And what smells odd? It is a quite normal way. I would only suggest to pass the `stream` to the task as a parameter.

Comment: @Erno no. How would I start it?

Comment: @ie There seems to be a lot of different ways of implementing the pattern, and I always have some skepticism towards this.

Comment: akton is right about using the BCL method for this, but: if you had to do it manually, it would be something like: http://pastie.org/4660897 - but don't use this since a BCL method exists!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Stream.WriteAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.writeasync.aspx) method instead and transfer the work of handling asynchronicity onto the base class library. There is also a ReadAsync for code not included in the example above.

Comment: I see. If I call the WriteAsync without `await` keyword, will it still then be asynchronous?

Comment: It will return a `Task<>` object instead and you can check it manually. If you want the call to block until results are returned, use the non-async methods. Alternatively, try the BeginWrite...EndWrite and BeginRead...EndRead methods for an older async implementation.